# I am getting a 500 server error in Flask when I try to bcrypt or scrypt a password

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, psycopg2, bcrypt

I'm new to Flask and was just learning my way around things by making a basic application, but I was having trouble with password storage.  I am using postgresql and psycopg2 with [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bcrypt/1.0.2) bcrypt package.  Everything works fine if I don't try to protect the password at all or when I use SHA256, but when I attempt to use bcrypt, I get a 500 server error.  Here's my code:

```
uname = request.form['uname']
passwd = bcrypt.hashpw(request.form['passwd'], bcrypt.gensalt())
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=flask user=postgres host=127.0.0.1 password=mypassword")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("INSERT INTO users (uname, passwd) VALUES (%s, %s)", (uname, passwd))
conn.commit()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Does anyone know why I am getting this problem?  Could bcrypt just be taking to long?  It didn't seem to take too long to load before I got the error back, but could that still be it?  My main goal was to use bcrypt, but I swapped it out for scrypt just to check and that didn't work either.

Comment: try to run server by `Debug=True`, then you can see whats going on

Comment: As Liteye said, run the server with Debug=True. You'll get a call stack that also includes an interpreter at each level of the call stack. It's one of the most useful parts of flask.

Comment: Can't be sure about the specifics for your error with out debug info, but a more Flask optimized approach might be to use the Flask-Bcrypt extension.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I hope people having the same problem will be helped quicker this way.

We had this problem, debug=true showed us what was wrong. The encoding wasn't correct for bcrypt. This should fix it.

```
passwd = bcrypt.hashpw(str(request.form['passwd']), bcrypt.gensalt())
```